# How to have differents sites share the same tables of DB?

Tags: customization, multisite, database, wpdb, wp-config

I want to have multiple versions of my site that share the same database.
I'm wondering if this is as simple as just cloning the site and then in the wp-config having them all use the same database?
Will they be able to queue each query appropriately and not conflict? (i'd have them all be on the same server, using different addon domains with cpanel)

I also looked at this method: http://www.wphostinggeeks.com/install-wp-multisite-with-top-level-domains/

Which talks about making a multi-site network.  but it sounds like with this they use the same database but different tables.  I want my sites to share users, and plugin tables that store data.  All sites will have different TLD.

Thanks for any help on this:)

Comment: And how about content? Should these sites have the same posts, pages, and so on? How about the process of editing that content?

Comment: Multisite *does* share users and plugins. (The users can be given different capabilities on different sites within the Multisite network, and the plugins can be activated on one, some, or all of the sites.) The separate tables in a Multisite network are all about keeping the sites' **content** and **settings** separate.